# QLabel->setText(pointer)

Tags: c++, qt

Допустим есть указатель на обьект класса  Qt (например `QPushButton *btn`). Хочу выводить адрес, на который ссылается указатель, через QLabel на виджет.

Comment: Преобразуйте к `int` и выводите. В чём проблема?

Comment: @V-Mor только `uintptr_t` или `size_t`, при отсутствии первого.